# What is the difference between Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) and Google Compute Engine (GCE) in term of server management?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I believe that the Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) is running on Google Compute Engine (GCE). So, what is the real advantage of using Google Kubernetes Engine in terms of server management?

I am referring to updates to the OS and security patches just like Google App Engine handles this for us. Does the SRE handle the update and security patches?

I know that Google App Engine already does this for us (updating the OS etc.), but on GAE, we are not able to attach a persistent disk.

My plan is to host a flat file CMS, which in this case, does not need for cloud SQL, cloud datastore, etc. Also, cloud memory store is way too expensive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A big difference between the two is that a normal GCE VM instance is completely unmanaged. Once you've used the GCP-provided image, all updates are up to you. Whereas with GKE, the Master and node versions can be set to upgrade automatically and you only choose which OS you want, not the specific OS version.

This means that if there are security patches or updates to a node OS, it will get pushed to your cluster. When there are improvements or patches to GKE (as long as you enable automatic upgrades) your nodes will receive the new versions.

GKE may cost you a little more than a stand-alone GCE VM, but it comes with more automation and management baked in.

Comment: + also cost to hire proper devops engineer

Comment: Agreed, there is also the learning curve of development when changing from standard servers to containers. The plus side is you can eventually move to full serverless, so I would argue it's worth the investment if you can

Comment: I disagree because in Google Compute Engine you can have managed instance groups and get similar benefits such automatic updates, autohealing, etc

Comment: you don't get automatic updates with an autoscaling group, you need to ensure the image being used is updated regularly. GKE handles that for you. GKE also means that if a node fails, the workload will just move to another node, it tends to recover quicker